# How to check data redundancy on float32 variable in C?

Tags: c, function, floating-point, logical-operators

I would like to check data corruption of a variable in some function. In general, if it is a unsigned integer variable i can easily check like below method

**sender side:**

```
uint8 actual_data = 23;
uint8 send_data = ~actual_data; /*bitwise NOT*/
send_data_to_other(send_data, actual_data);
```

**receiver side:**

```
void receive_data_to_other(uint8 received_data, uint8 actual_data)
{
   uint8 check_data = ~received_data;
   if(check_data == actual_data)
   {
     printf("data is correct");
   }
   else
   {
     printf("something wrong")
   }
}
```

But suppose if i am using `float32` data,

eg: `float32 actual_data = 23.22f;`

then i can not perform bitwise NOT(`~`) for float32 variables.
Any one Suggest me how can we check the data verification for float32 variable in C?

Comment: There's nothing magical about `not` - you could just send the float data twice and compare at the receiving end.

Comment: @Internal Server Error What you mean by send twice ?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: A physical defect that clears a certain bit may go undetected in a duplicate transmission whereas it will not in an inverted transmission.

Comment: Same as what you do with `uint8`, but omit the `not` part.

Comment: Unrelated: Your method of sending `{data, ~data}` has 100% overhead, but is not even able to correct a single bit error. And if you accidentally have two bit errors at the same position, you would not even detect it. I recommend reading about e.g., "Hamming code" or more general https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_detection_and_correction

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `sizeof (float) == sizeof (uint32_t)`:

```
    uint32_t data;
    uint32_t ndata;

    memcpy(&data, &f, sizeof(data));
    ndata = ~data;
```

But of course, your send function will need to send larger chunks of data.

To "reconstruct" float you will need to copy data in the opposite direction.

```
float toFloat(uint32_t data)
{
    float f;

    memcpy(&f, &data, sizeof(f));
    return f;
}
```

Do not worry about `memcpy` overhead as this function is very well known to the compiler and optimizing compilers will optimize out the call.